# Retrieving POSTED data from controller

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using angular js. I posted data to a controller in vb.net from a JS file. How can I retrieve the data in the vb controller?.

Below is my app.factory method.

```js
UpdateServiceData: function (p1, p2) {
            var data = $.param({
                fName: "John",
                lName: "Smith"
            });

            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }            

            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: '../api/Service/UpdateSvcData',                                                    
                data,
                config,
                params: {
                    'P1': p1,
                    'P2': p2
     }
                }
            });                         
        }
```

UpdateSvcData is a method inside the controller ServiceController.vb

I just need to retrieve the posted values inside ServiceController.vb
i.e., I need to get fName and lName.

In short, I'm posting values from a JS file. I need to retrieve it at the ServiceController.vb using vb.net

I tried Request.QueryString("fName"), Request.Form["fName"] etc. But these are not giving the results.

Thanks

```
Public Function UpdateServiceData(<FromUri()> request As ServiceEntities) As HttpResponseMessage

Dim success As Boolean = True
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage
Try
    Dim dataAccess As DB.DataAccessBase = DB.DataAccessBase.GetInstance(DataAcessTypes.Service)


    request.MethodName = "UpdateServiceData"

    Dim sJSON As String = dataAccess.Select(Of ServiceEntities)(request)
    response = Me.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    response.Content = New StringContent(sJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
Catch ex As Exception
    response = Me.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
End Try

Return response
End Function
```

Comment: Can you share any sample code? What have you tried so far? Are you talking about a Web API controller or an MVC one?

Comment: Thanks @trnelson for checking my question. I updated it with more details. I'm using Web API controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the $http object to the controller if I understand your question, hard to tell without seeing the controller though.